# getting static file for django with nginx

Tags: django, docker, nginx, django-staticfiles

im trying to get static files in django, when using an nginx reverse proxy, dockerized in an ec2 container

i have a django project and when it is dockerized with nginx as a proxy server i can not find my static files

my default-ssl.conf.tpl for my nginx server has

```
  location /static{
    alias /vol/static;
  }
```

and my dockerfile for nginx says to creates a volume for vol/static

```
VOLUME /vol/static
VOLUME /vol/www
```

so i manually put my files in there with docker cp and check with exec to make sure they're there
my files are now in vol/static on my proxy container. so i think they should be handled properly now
i still get

```
GET https://tgmjack.com/static/health_hud.png 404 (Not Found)
```

:(

what might i have done wrong?
what other info would be useful?

my full code is here incase that might reveal what ive done wrong
https://github.com/tgmjack/god_help_me

extra info

im deploying on an ec2 container
i can connect to my custom domain with https and everything seems to be fine except the files cant be found

Comment: `/vol/static` how do you deliver your files here?

Comment: i did it manually with docker cp, then checked manually too by opening the docker container with docker exec xxxx /bin/bash and going to vol/static

Answer (score 0):

I checked your github-repo.

First: You don't want to organize the static folder yourself. Django offers a really nice convenience method for it: `python manage.py collectstatic`.

Only thing you need to setup is:

- `STATIC_URL` in settings.py - that you have done
- `STATIC_ROOT` in settings.py - that you have not done ([info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#static-root))
- Then put all your static files in folders organized like this

```
app/
- static/ --> here general static files that get used by all apps
- app/
- home/
-- static/ --> here specific static files that get used by home-app specifically
```

- Then run `python manage.py collectstatic` ([info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/#deployment))

You want to do it this way because:

- Django will find your staticfiles afterwards
- It deals with the permissions
- It also sets up the staticfiles for the admin page for example and all other apps.